# Ansible filter dict based on key presence and list values

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have this variable :

```
components:
  comp_one:
    name: first_component
    remote_server_path: "/tmp/path/one"
    binaries:
      - test
      - test_two


  comp_two:
    name: second_component
    remote_server_path: "/tmp/path/two"
    binaries:
      - ed_test
      - ed_test_2

  comp_three:
    name: third_component
    remote_server_path: "/tmp/path/three"
```

What I'm trying to achieve, is to only keep sub-dictionaries of `components` that has key `binaries`, and the filter those binaries using my `group_names`. Also, D'd like to only keep dict keys `binaries` and `remote_server_path`.

For example, if i have this hosts.yaml :

```
---
all:
  children:
    kubernetes_dev:
      children:
        ed_test:
          hosts:
            host_one:
              ansible_host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
              ansible_ssh_user: ansible
        test_two:
          hosts:
            host_one:
              ansible_host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
              ansible_ssh_user: ansible
        test:
          hosts:
            host_one:
              ansible_host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
              ansible_ssh_user: ansible
```

The expected output would be :

```
comp_one:
  remote_server_path: "/tmp/path/one"
  binaries:
    - test
    - test_two

comp_two:
  remote_server_path: "/tmp/path/two"
  binaries:
    - ed_test
```

I've successfully filtered the `comp_three` dict using this :

```
- name: Debug
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ components | dict2items | selectattr('value.binaries', 'defined') }}"
```

But, I can't figure out a way to only select `binaries` and `remote_server_path` keys while filtering with my `group_names.

Does anyone can't help me find a clean way to do this ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [*group_names*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#magic-variables). This is: *"List of groups the current host is part of."*. For the host *host_one* in the inventory *hosts.yaml* this is

```yaml
  group_names: [ed_test, test, test_two]
```

Convert the dictionary *components* to list and test [*intersect*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory) of *binaries* and *group_names*. Default to empty list if the attribute *binaries* is missing

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        selected_list: "{{ selected_list|d([]) + [_item] }}"
      loop: "{{ components|dict2items }}"
      when: my_groups|length > 0
      vars:
        _item: "{{ item|combine(my_value) }}"
        my_value: "{{ {'value': {'binaries': my_groups,
                                'remote_server_path': item.value.remote_server_path}} }}"
        my_groups: "{{ item.value.binaries|d([])|intersect(group_names) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  selected_list:
  - key: comp_one
    value:
      binaries:
      - test
      - test_two
      remote_server_path: /tmp/path/one
  - key: comp_two
    value:
      binaries:
      - ed_test
      remote_server_path: /tmp/path/two
```

Conver the list into a dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        selected_dict: "{{ selected_list|items2dict }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  selected_dict:
    comp_one:
      binaries:
      - test
      - test_two
      remote_server_path: /tmp/path/one
    comp_two:
      binaries:
      - ed_test
      remote_server_path: /tmp/path/two
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    components:
      comp_one:
        name: first_component
        remote_server_path: /tmp/path/one
        binaries:
          - test
          - test_two
      comp_two:
        name: second_component
        remote_server_path: /tmp/path/two
        binaries:
          - ed_test
          - ed_test_2
      comp_three:
        name: third_component
        remote_server_path: /tmp/path/three
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        selected_list: "{{ selected_list|d([]) + [_item] }}"
      loop: "{{ components|dict2items }}"
      when: my_groups|length > 0
      vars:
        _item: "{{ item|combine(my_value) }}"
        my_value: "{{ {'value': {'binaries': my_groups,
                                'remote_server_path': item.value.remote_server_path}} }}"
        my_groups: "{{ item.value.binaries|d([])|intersect(group_names) }}"
    - set_fact:
        selected_dict: "{{ selected_list|items2dict }}"
    - debug:
        var: selected_dict
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it's just missing one thing. As you may have noticed, I've `ed_test_2` on `comp_two` binaries but not on my hosts, and I'm not expecting it to be there

Comment: Right. I fixed the code.